# How to avoid memory leaks using ShellExecuteEx?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, memory-leaks

Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example:

Visual Studio 2017 Pro 15.9.3
Windows 10 "1803" (17134.441) x64
Environment variable `OANOCACHE` set to 1.
Data/Screenshots shown for a 32 bits Unicode build.

UPDATE: Exact same behavior on another machine with Windows 10 "1803" (17134.407)
UPDATE: ZERO leaks on an old Laptop with Windows Seven
UPDATE: Exact same behavior (leaks) on another machine with W10 "1803" (17134.335)

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <cstdio>

int main() {

    getchar();
    CoInitializeEx( NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED | COINIT_DISABLE_OLE1DDE );
    printf( "Launching and terminating processes...\n" );
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < 64; ++i ) {

        SHELLEXECUTEINFO sei;
        memset( &sei, 0, sizeof( sei ) );
        sei.cbSize = sizeof( sei );
        sei.lpFile = L"iexplore.exe";
        sei.lpParameters = L"about:blank";
        sei.fMask = SEE_MASK_FLAG_NO_UI | SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS | SEE_MASK_NOASYNC;
        BOOL bSuccess = ShellExecuteEx( &sei );
        if ( bSuccess == FALSE ) {
            printf( "\nShellExecuteEx failed with Win32 code %d and hInstApp %d. Exiting...\n",
                    GetLastError(), (int)sei.hInstApp );
            CoUninitialize();
            return 0;
        } // endif
        printf( "%d", (int)GetProcessId( sei.hProcess ) );
        Sleep( 1000 );
        bSuccess = TerminateProcess( sei.hProcess, 0 );
        if ( bSuccess == FALSE ) {
            printf( "\nTerminateProcess failed with Win32 code %d. Exiting...\n",
                    GetLastError() );
            CloseHandle( sei.hProcess );
            CoUninitialize();
            return 0;
        } // endif
        DWORD dwRetCode = WaitForSingleObject( sei.hProcess, 5000 );
        if ( dwRetCode != WAIT_OBJECT_0 ) {
            printf( "\nWaitForSingleObject failed with code %x. Exiting...\n",
                    dwRetCode );
            CloseHandle( sei.hProcess );
            CoUninitialize();
            return 0;
        } // endif
        CloseHandle( sei.hProcess );
        printf( "K " );
        Sleep( 1000 );
    } // end for
    printf( "\nDone!" );
    CoUninitialize();
    getchar();

} // main
```

The code use [ShellExecuteEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shellexecuteexw) to launch, in a loop, 64 instances of Internet Explorer with the `about:blank` URL. The `SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS` is used to be able to then use the [TerminateProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-terminateprocess) API.

I notice two kinds of leaks:

1. Handles leaks: launching Process Explorer when the loop is finished but the program still running, I see several blocks of 64 handles (process handles, and registries handles for various keys)
2. Memory leaks: attaching the visual C++ 2017 debugger to the program, before the loop, I took a first Heap Snapshot, and a second one after the loop.I see 64 blocs of 8192 bytes, coming from   `windows.storage.dll!CInvokeCreateProcessVerb::_BuildEnvironmentForNewProcess()`

You can read some information about the handles leaks here: [ShellExecute leaks handles](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/33bade27-ad82-49a7-b9fa-f8eb55803470/shellexecute-leaks-handles)

Here are some screenshots:
First, the PID launched and terminated:
[image: PID Launched and terminated]

Second: the same pids, as seen in Process Explorer:
[image: Process Handles]

Process Explorer also shows 64*3 open registry handles, for `HKCR\.exe`, `HKCR\exefile` and `HKCR\exefile\shell\open`.

[image: Registry Handles leaks]

One of the 64 leaked "Environment" (8192 bytes and the callstack):
[image: Visual Studio 2017 Heap Snapshot]

Last: a screen shot of Process Explorer, showing the "Private Bytes" during the execution of the MCVE modified with a 1024 loop counter. The running time is approximately 36 minutes, the PV start at 1.1 Mo (before CoInitializeEx) and end at 19 Mo (after CoUninitialize). The value then stabilizes at 18.9
[image: Process Explorer Private Bytes (1024 ShellExecuteEx]

What am I doing wrong?
Do I see leaks where there are none?

Comment: Have you verified, that the memory leaks are real? Maybe they are just an artifact of a cache implementation that confuses leak detection tools.

Comment: I just ran the Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example again, with a 1024 loop, instead of 64, in Release mode, with no debugger attached. The process started using 880 ko and ended at 18Mo... Process Explorer shows tons of handles to the same registry keys and dead processes. If that's caching, it's utterly broken.

Comment: @IInspectable How can I verify "that the memory leaks are real"?

Comment: It's not the caching, that's at fault. It is the tools, that have a hard time distinguishing between a true resource leak and a resource entering a caching scheme they are unaware of. COM resource handling in particular is inherently hard to diagnose using standard tools. I'm not suggesting, that there is no leak, just that you need to be careful to understand and properly interpret the data you gathered.

Comment: @IInspectable Ok. But if it starts with <1Mo and finish with 18Mo and with the handles still visible in Process Explorer, I think there is a real bug.

Comment: That doesn't necessarily mean there is a bug or leak. [Caches are nice, but they confuse memory leak detection tools](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20091127-00/?p=15883) has some useful information and links to related articles. [Why is there a BSTR cache anyway?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150107-00/?p=43203) may be immediately applicable. Try the approach from the first article to disable a particular sort of caching and see, if that makes a difference. Also note, that in Microsoft's C++ implementation the heap can never shrink.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184622/discussion-between-manuell-and-iinspectable).

Comment: Could I know why the downvote?

Comment: Unlikely to get rationale for a vote, that rarely happens. A few things you can do to improve the question: `1` Do mention that the observed behavior doesn't change when you define the `OANOCACHE` environment variable. `2` Install the English language pack for Visual Studio and include screenshots in English. `3` Note the specific Windows version you are using. `4` Show code that follows the STA rules (dispatching messages as required). `5` Be specific about the type of memory that increases (private bytes vs. working set).

Comment: @IInspectable thank you.

Comment: are you test this on another systems ? install say the same windows version on vmvare and test here.

Comment: ShellExecute is the door to a complete world. So far, that proves nothing (because it's very very hard to prove a physical leak from something you don't have the source of). Have you checked what dlls are loaded into your explorer.exe processes? Explorer is (3rd) party time for all kind of stuff (printer things, shell extensions - including CLR powered ones, etc.).

Comment: @RbMn I didn't test on another system.

Comment: @SimonMourier I don't understand what you are talking about. There is no "explorer.exe" here. And if processes, threads, and registry keys handles not closed "prove nothing", I would like to know what is necessary.

Comment: @manuell - oops my bad I mixed up things. But that doesn't change my other comments. The shell uses a lot of caches in general. For example, if you look down the _BuildEnvironmentForNewProcess path, you'll see it uses classes such as "_AllocStringWorker" whatever could that mean. Maybe the shell designers have chosen to allocate memory or handles if there's enough, and free them only when they're happy to do so. What real problem does this poses to you?

Comment: @SimonMourier Real problem is shown in the last screen shot. With a 1024 loop, you end up with literally thousands of leaked handles and 1024 blocks of 8192 bytes. That's not caching, that's leaking.

Comment: Only Microsoft could tell you if it's a leak or not, it may completely be by design. And I still don't understand what your "real" problem is.

Comment: @SimonMourier - this of course can not be leak **by design**. and not only microsoft can say leak reason on concrete system. not hard research this under debugger. *I didn't test on another system.* - this is first what you need todo. i guess that really leak only in your concrete system (some 3-rd party shell extension, etc. anyway need look on another (but same version) windows and look under debugger where exist this leaks

Comment: @RbMm - I'm not talking about leak by design, but cache by design. You'd have to analyze the program as a whole to really know. It's not because you see an allocation somewhere that there's not a corresponding deallocation elsewhere that will happen "sometimes". That's all I'm saying.

Comment: @RbMn Updated the question with tests on 3 other machines (Windows 7 OK, Windows 10 "1803" KO)

Comment: @SimonMourier - this can not be cache. cache process handle absolute senseless. this is 100%

Comment: @manuell - yes, just look this on 1803 - really, this handle leaks exist. of course this is serious windows bug. need some time for look where and why exactly (on 1709 no such bug)

Comment: really good catch. this is critical windows bug. *explorer.exe* and any processes who call `ShellExecute[Ex]` affected by this. huge resource leaks. interesting are this is fixed in new windows versions (i until not have latest windows builds installed). some late today write detail report where exactly bug in shell32 code

Comment: @RbMm Thanks. As far as I know, the first one was "
fheidenreich" here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/33bade27-ad82-49a7-b9fa-f8eb55803470/shellexecute-leaks-handles

Comment: @IInspectable I updated the question with information on reproduction on different machines. For your information, I also tested in a windowed application (basically, calling the MCVE code in a WM_TIMER): same results.

Comment: i until not finish research, look like mistake in reference counting of objects based on `CExecuteCommandBase`. need near 1 hour +/-. you not need have any message loops, sta, etc. all this sugestion is nonsense. this is clear windows bug. if can - try test this on latest windows builds - are bug fixed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is windows bug, in version 1803. minimal code for reproduce:

```
if (0 <= CoInitialize(0))
{
    SHELLEXECUTEINFO sei = {
        sizeof(sei), 0, 0, 0, L"notepad.exe", 0, 0, SW_SHOW
    };

    ShellExecuteEx( &sei );

    CoUninitialize();
}
```

after execute this code, can view handles for notepad.exe process and first thread - this handles of course must not exist (be closed), not closed keys

```
\REGISTRY\MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\.exe
\REGISTRY\MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\exefile
```

also private memory leaks exist in process after this call.

of course this bug cause permanent resource leaks in *explorer.exe* and any process, which use `ShellExecute[Ex]`

exactly research of this bug - [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/33bade27-ad82-49a7-b9fa-f8eb55803470/shellexecute-leaks-handles?forum=windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues)

> The underlying issue here appears to be in **windows.storage.dll**. In
>   particular, the **`CInvokeCreateProcessVerb`** object is never
>   destroyed, because the associated reference count never reaches 0.
>   This leaks all of the objects associated with
>   **`CInvokeCreateProcessVerb`**, including 4 handles and some memory.
>
> The reason the reference count never reaches 0 appears to be related
>   to the argument change for `ShellDDEExec::InitializeByShellInternal`
>   from Windows 10 1709 to 1803, executed by
>   `CInvokeCreateProcessVerb::Launch()`.

more concrete here we have cyclic reference of an object (`CInvokeCreateProcessVerb`) to itself.

more concrete error inside method `CInvokeCreateProcessVerb::Launch()` which call from self

```
HRESULT ShellDDEExec::InitializeByShellInternal(
    IAssociationElement*, 
    CreateProcessMethod,
    PCWSTR,
    STARTUPINFOEXW*, 
    IShellItem2*, 
    IUnknown*, // !!!
    PCWSTR, 
    PCWSTR, 
    PCWSTR);
```

with wrong 6 argument. the `CInvokeCreateProcessVerb` class containing internal `ShellDDEExec` sub-object. in windows 1709 `CInvokeCreateProcessVerb::Launch()` pass pointer to `static_cast<IServiceProvider*>(pObj)` in place 6 argument to `ShellDDEExec::InitializeByShellInternal` where `pObj` is point to instance of `CBindAndInvokeStaticVerb` class. but in 1803 version here passed pointer to `static_cast<IServiceProvider*>(this)` - so pointer to **self**. the `InitializeByShellInternal` store this pointer inside self and add reference to it. note that `ShellDDEExec` is **sub-object** of `CInvokeCreateProcessVerb`. so destructor of `ShellDDEExec` will not be called until destructor of `CInvokeCreateProcessVerb` not be called. but destructor of `CInvokeCreateProcessVerb` will be not called until it reference count reach 0. but this not happens until `ShellDDEExec` not release self pointer to `CInvokeCreateProcessVerb` which will be only inside it destructor ..

may be this more visible in pseudo code

```
class ShellDDEExec
{
    CComPtr<IUnknown*> _pUnk;

    HRESULT InitializeByShellInternal(..IUnknown* pUnk..)
    {
        _pUnk = pUnk;
    }
};

class CInvokeCreateProcessVerb : CExecuteCommandBase, IServiceProvider /**/
{
    IServiceProvider* _pVerb;//point to static_cast<IServiceProvider*>(CBindAndInvokeStaticVerb*)
    ShellDDEExec _exec;

    TRYRESULT CInvokeCreateProcessVerb::Launch()
    {
        // in 1709
        // _exec.InitializeByShellInternal(_pVerb); 
        // in 1803
        _exec.InitializeByShellInternal(..static_cast<IServiceProvider*>(this)..); // !! error !!
    }
};
```

`ShellDDEExec::_pUnk` hold pointer to containing object `CInvokeCreateProcessVerb` this pointer will be released only inside `CComPtr` destructor, called from `ShellDDEExec` destructor. called from `CInvokeCreateProcessVerb` destructor, called when reference count became 0, but this never happens because extra reference hold `ShellDDEExec::_pUnk`

so object store referenced pointer to self. after this reference count to `CInvokeCreateProcessVerb` never reaches 0

Comment: Thanks. Will probably accept & award. Do you know if there is some sort of official "ticket" open at  Microsoft, or how can I browse/open that kind of bug reporting?

Comment: @manuell - no, my task is debugging and research. official "ticket"not my area

Comment: Closing the loop: The bug is fixed in 1809. (Trivia: I had identified the bug internally in April, but the fix didn't go out until September.)

Comment: @RaymondChen some time this happens ). unrelated - long time was bug in `DnsQueryEx` api, if call it in asynchronous mode, with callback, and pass say "localhost" to resolve. api return synchronous `ERROR_SUCCESS` but `pQueryRecords` is 0 pointer. so no results. really `DnsRecord` is allocated, but "lost". as result we not got data on return and memory leak. however this is fixed on some win11 version